# What kind of control does Master of Nature give?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, mind-control

The Master of Nature feature for nature domain clerics lets you command creatures charmed by Charm Animals and Plants.

How specific is this command? Is it like taking control via the "total and precise control" in Dominate Person or more similar to the general command?

Answer (score 9):

The normal charmed condition only generates friendly feelings.

> **[Charmed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed)**
>
> - A charmed creature can't attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

As an enhancement to *Channel Divinity: Charm Animals and Plants* gives you an extra option - issuing instructions.

> **[Master of Nature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/cleric#NatureDomain)**
>
> At 17th level, you gain the ability to command animals and plant creatures. While creatures are [charmed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed) by your Charm Animals and Plants feature, you can take a bonus action on your turn to verbally command what each of those creatures will do on its next turn.

It is different from *[Dominate Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-person)*, because issuing instructions takes a bonus action and has to be done verbally (Dominate person is telepathic and doesn't take an action). If *Master of Nature* was meant to have the total-and-precise option that *Dominate Person* does, it would say so.

Like most things in 5E, it does what it says on the tin... You spend a bonus action to give instructions, and the subject obeys on its next turn. The subject doesn't even get a new save or anything like that.

It's worth noting that *Channel Divinity: Charm Animals and Plants* is different from, and somewhat more fragile than, *[Charm Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person)*, too. *Charm Person* breaks if the subject's new friends do any harm to it, the *Channel Divinity* breaks if the subject takes *any* damage. On the flipside, it's more powerful in a different way, because it has a 30' radius and potentially affects *every* plant and beast in the area.